# TypeORM returning invalid amount of results with take

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am having trouble implementing pagination with TypeORM. My issue is as follows;
I have entity A with a PK of userID and property of one to many to entity B.

Now, when I perform my query, I innerJoinAndSelect() relation B to A.
At times, I will want to orderBy() my query based on a column belonging to entity B (the relation entity).
When I do that, it seems like multiple results of the same UserID will return and then narrow down since the query does distinct by the PK of entity A.
This way I am getting an unexpected behaviour on behalf of TypeORM since I expect to receive back 40 results for example and only get 36 because I had 4 duplicate rows. Duplicate as in same entity A value but with different value of entity B.

Here's how it works basically:

If an orderBy is specified, add it to the query builder.
The issue occurs when the orderBy property is of relation B.

```js
if (searchParameters.orderBy !== undefined) {
      queryBuilder = queryBuilder.addOrderBy(searchParameters.orderBy.field, searchParameters.orderBy.method);
    }
```

Then, I build the query with all the wheres, ands and ors.

Eventually, fetch with pagination like so:

```js
    const res = await queryBuilder
      .skip((pagination.page * Number(pagination.size)))
      .take(Number(pagination.size+1))
      .getMany();
```

Then, say pagination.size is 40, I'll get less than 40 results even though there is more than that. That's probably due to the duplication.

Is that how it's supposed to work? How do I overcome this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add code examples.

Comment: Added slices of code where I use orderBy and fetch with pagination

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? im facing the same